# Use Firebase database in notifications sending

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-notifications

What I want is to be able to use Firebase Console to send push notifications to users that I have registered in firebase database. I'd want to filter them by some topics/values stored in their user object. Is it possible?

Comment: why use firebase console and not a custom server ?

Comment: because its use is simple and can be shared to other google accounts, and the most important reason: don't have time to implement a custom server...

Comment: but it can't me modified for custom needs which you want (like filtering topics etc)

Comment: I thought console could query from users stored in firebase db, and could filter throught its key/values... but it seems it needs much more development... But console allows topics filtering, which can be improved a lot because right now you are not able to create topic categories...

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no integration between Firebase database and Notifications. Have you stored FCM registrations in the database? If they are subscribed to some topic then you can send to that but you would need to do it manually.

Comment: so what are the benfits of using firebase database? If I have to query it and manually send notifications, why don't store firebase token in a custom db and read from it when sending notifications?